# batch script that kills java processes

Tags: windows, batch-file

So my batch script kills a random java process every 10 seconds.
My goal is to make it every random amount seconds between 5 and 25.
Any idea how I would do that?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%T in ('tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq java.exe" /fo csv') do (
    taskkill /F /pid %%~T 
    timeout /t 10
  goto :start
)
```

Comment: One, that's not bash (that is a dos batch or command file). Two, **why**?

Comment: And three, it sounds like what this question is _really_ asking is how to generate a random number between 5 and 25 in this language. So, just ask that question. The Java portion is irrelevant, so please pick the correct language, and tag that. (And maybe also re-do your search, because chances are good that there is already info out there on how to generate a random number in this language.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've of course looked for ways to generate a random number between 5 and 25 but simply could not implement them into the rest of my script and that's why I posted it all.

Comment: I also thought it was a bash script but couldn't find the tag and that's why I did Java, now that Elliott said it's a dos batch or command file I can properly tag my question.

Comment: I don't know dos batch syntax, but generally there would be three steps in integrating the random number into the sleep: (1) generating the random value (2) saving it to a variable (3) using that variable instead of the hard-coded 10. You should clarify which of those steps is giving you trouble.

Comment: *" that's why I did Java "* ... That is illogical.  Not to mention rude.  You are supposed to figure out how to ask a question >>before<< you ask one.

Comment: Please post the code that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you had at least searched here for "random", you'd have found code similar to:

```bat
Set/A Delay=%random% %%21 +5
```

You could have then used:

```bat
Timeout %Delay% /NoBreak>Nul
```

If you were to:

```bat
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

You could use:

```bat
Set/A Delay=!random! %%21 +5
```

and:

```bat
Timeout !Delay! /NoBreak>Nul
```